# How can i use my own rosbag version

Tags: rosbag

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hi,

I need to be able to set the duration for a rosbag play command.
This feature is not implemented in rosbag yet, there is a pull request though.

Since I need this feature now I would either have to stop the rosbag play process at an given time or I would have to implement it in my own rosbag branch. When I am using my own rosbag branch I will also have to install this custom branch on other computers which will use my package.

Is there a nice way to do any of this?

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/54557/how-can-i-use-my-own-rosbag-version/) by [Josch](https://answers.ros.org/users/3932/josch/) on ROS Answers with karma: 230 on 2013-02-06

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

You can checkout the rosbag package into a catkin workspace, make arbitrary changes to it and than build the workspace with "catkin_make". After that you source the setup.bash from that workspace instead of /opt/ros/groovy and your version of rosbag overlays the installed one.

This is how you can override any catkin package in ROS.

---

Originally posted by [Dirk Thomas](https://answers.ros.org/users/2575/dirk-thomas/) with karma: 16276 on 2013-03-01

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 2

Answer (score 0):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Maybe I misunderstood, what you want to do, but I don't really see a way out of your problem. As long as your pull request isn't processed, there is not other way than actually using a custom version wherever you need it.

For your specific problem there is a solution though. If you only want to play a bag file for a certain time, you can create a new bag file that only contains data up to that time. A standard rosbag play would then do the right thing.
`rosbag filter` is what you are looking for.

---

Originally posted by [dornhege](https://answers.ros.org/users/122/dornhege/) with karma: 31395 on 2013-02-06

This answer was **NOT ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [Josch](https://answers.ros.org/users/3932/josch/) on 2013-02-11**:
My application should preferably run in real time. So if it would create a filtered bag first it would need some time. The bags I will use are about 1-3 hours long, rosbag filter needs some time then.